How can I use moviepy's .write_videofile with io.BytesIO?
Is it possible to bypass storage on a filesystem with io.BytesIO and moviepy? I need to have everything stored in memory for a docker container.

Yes, you can use io.BytesIO with MoviePy to write video files directly to memory instead of file:
pip install moviepy

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, TextClip, CompositeVideoClip
...

output = io.BytesIO()
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-s', '640x480', '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24', '-r', '30', '-i', '-', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-f', 'mp4', 'pipe:1'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
for frame in video.iter_frames(fps=30, dtype='uint8'):
    process.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
process.stdin.close()
output.write(process.stdout.read())
output.seek(0)


Find details of MoviePy here: https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/

This seems like it will deadlock if the stdout pipe buffer fills up, which is pretty likely given the amount of data expected.
